# Guarantees concerning Math.atan2

Tags: java, math

The documentation for [Math.atan2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2-double-double-) says

> The computed result must be within 2 ulps of the exact result.

The fact that it says 2 ulps presumably means there are cases where the returned value is not the closest `double` to the true result. Does anyone know if it is guaranteed to return the same value for equivalent pairs of `int` parameters? In other words, if `a`, `b` and `k` are positive `int` values and neither `a * k` nor `b * k` overflows, is it guaranteed that

```
Math.atan2(a, b) == Math.atan2(a * k, b * k)
```

**Edit**

Note that this is definitely not the case for non-overflowing `long` multiplications. For example

```
long a = 959786689;
long b = 363236985;
long k = 9675271;
System.out.println(Math.atan2(a, b));
System.out.println(Math.atan2(a * k, b * k));
```

prints

```
1.2089992287797169
1.208999228779717
```

but I could not find an example in `int` values.

Comment: If it doesn't tell you that it's guaranteed, it isn't guaranteed. Maybe the current implementation is that way, but it doesn't mean it has to stay that way.

Answer (score 7):

> Does anyone know if it is guaranteed to return the same value for equivalent pairs of int parameters?

Simply put, no. The `Math` documentation *is* the source of truth, and it provides no guarantee beyond the 2 ulp limit you reference. This is by design (as we'll see below), therefore any other source is either exposing an implementation detail or simply wrong.

Attempting to find lower bounds heuristically is impractical, since the behavior of [`Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) is documented to be platform-specific:

> Unlike some of the numeric methods of class `StrictMath`, all implementations of the equivalent functions of class `Math` are not defined to return the bit-for-bit same results. This relaxation permits better-performing implementations where strict reproducibility is not required.

Therefore even if you see tighter bounds in your tests there is no reason to believe these bounds are portable across platforms, processors, or Java versions.

However, as `Math`'s documentation notes, [`StrictMath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html) has more explicit behavior. `StrictMath` is documented to perform consistently across platforms, and is expected to have the same behavior as the reference implementation [`fdlibm`](http://netlib.org/fdlibm/index.html). That project's [`readme`](http://netlib.org/fdlibm/readme) notes:

> FDLIBM is intended to provide a reasonably portable ... reference quality (below one ulp for major functions like sin,cos,exp,log) math library.

You can reference the [source code for `atan2`](http://netlib.org/fdlibm/e_atan2.c) and determine precise bounds by examining its implementation; any other implementations of `StrictMath.atan2()` are required to give the same results as the reference implementation.

It's interesting to note that `StrictMath.atan2()` doesn't include the same 2 ulp comment as `Math.atan2()`. While it would be nice if it repeated `fdlibm`'s "below one ulp" comment explicitly, I interpret the absence of this comment to mean `StrictMath`'s implementation does not need to include that caveat - it will always be below one ulp.

**tl;dr** if you need precise results or stable results cross-platform use `StrictMath`. `Math` trades off precision for speed.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit**: at first I thought this can be answered using "results must be semi-monotonic" requirement from the javadoc, but it actually can't be applied, so I re-wrote the answer.

Almost everything I can say is already covered by dimo414's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355486/guarantees-concerning-math-atan2/37559895#37559895). I just want to add: when using `Math.atan2` on the same platform or even when using `StrictMath.atan2` there is no formal guarantee (from the documentation) that `atan2(y, x) == atan2(y * k, x * k)`. Sure, `StrictMath`'s implementation actually uses `y / x`, so when `y / x` is precisely the same `double` value, the results will be equal (here I reasonably imply that function is deterministic), but keep it in mind.

Answering that part about `int` parameters: `int` holds 32 bits (actually, more like 31 bits plus one bit for sign) and can be represented by `double` type without any loss of precision, so no new problems there.

---

And the difference you described in the question (for non-overflowing `long` values) is caused by a loss of precision when converting `long` values to `double`, it has nothing to do with `Math.atan2` itself, and it happens before the function is even called. `double` type [can hold](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) only 53 bits of mantissa, but in your case `a * k` requires 54 bits, so it is rounded to the nearest number a `double` can represent (`b * k` is okay though, it requires only 52 bits):

```
long a = 959786689;
long b = 363236985;
long k = 9675271;

System.out.println(a * k);
System.out.println((double) (a * k));
System.out.println((long) (double) (a * k));
System.out.println((long) (double) (a * k) == a * k);

System.out.println(b * k);
System.out.println((double) (b * k));
System.out.println((long) (double) (b * k));
System.out.println((long) (double) (b * k) == b * k);
```

Output:

```
9286196318267719
9.28619631826772E15
9286196318267720
false
3514416267097935
3.514416267097935E15
3514416267097935
true
```

---

And to address the example from the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355486/guarantees-concerning-math-atan2#comment62605231_37555320):

We have `double a = 1.02551177480084, b = 1.12312341356234, k = 5;`. In this case none of `a`, `b`, `a * k`, `b * k` can be represented as `double` without loss of precision. I'll use `BigDecimal` to demonstrate it, because it can show the true (not rounded) value of `double`:

```
double a = 1.02551177480084;
System.out.println("a is            " + new BigDecimal(a));
System.out.println("a * 5 is        " + new BigDecimal(a * 5));
System.out.println("a * 5 should be " + new BigDecimal(a).multiply(new BigDecimal("5")));
```

outputs

```
a is            1.0255117748008399924941613789997063577175140380859375
a * 5 is        5.12755887400420018451541182002983987331390380859375   // precision loss here
a * 5 should be 5.1275588740041999624708068949985317885875701904296875
```

and the difference can be clearly seen (same can be done with `b` instead of `a`).

There is a more simple test (since `atan2()` essentially uses `a/b`):

```
double a = 1.02551177480084, b = 1.12312341356234, k = 5;
System.out.println(a / b == (a * k) / (b * k));
```

outputs

```
false
```

Comment: All but the last sentence of your answer can be deleted without loss of precision.

Comment: Funny, but not true - the question is not about `int` -> `double` conversion, but about `Math.atan2`, so at least the first 3 paragraphs should also stay.

Comment: Plus one for explaining why the `long` example doesn't work. However I'm not sure semi-monotonicity explains it. For example, I can find examples of `double` values `a`, `b` and `k` where no loss of precision occurs in the multiplications `a * k` and `b * k` (so the true mathematical values of `atan2` are exactly equal), yet `Math.asin2(a, b) != Math.asin2(a * k, b * k)`. For example `double a = 1.02551177480084, b = 1.12312341356234, k = 5;`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Added an update (I assume you mean `Math.atan2`, not `Math.asin2`).

Comment: @Roman You're right. I was testing those values using `BigDecimal.valueOf` rather than `new BigDecimal`. That's really dim of me.

Comment: @Bohemian In fact, the question was NOT "why it does not work for high longs?" (which is explained by the last sentence) but whether there is a guarantee. So, the real answer is in the first three paragraphs.

Comment: @Roman Giving this answer +1 because I really like the semi-monotonic observation. Plus the explanation of lost precision. Despite that, I would still say that it technically is not a real guarantee. Most definitions of "non-decreasing" state that for each a>b, there must be f(a)>=f(b) -- which says nothing about a==b. Theoretically, a function may return two different values for the same input parameter, while still fullfilling semi-monotonic definition.